# accessing c drive of a network computer using php

Tags: php, sqlite, drive

I am trying to access C drive of a network PC. I am able to access it using explorer writing this path `\\PCNAME\c$\path\to\file`. But when I tried accessing it using `copy` function of `php` its not working. Here is my `php` code.

```
copy("\\\\PCNAME\\c\$\\path\\to\\file","filename");
```

Is there any syntax error?
Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Cute post, looks like poetry. What's the error ?

Comment: Alex, that is what i was asking, is that any error in my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not

```
copy("\\PCNAME\c\$\path\to\file","filename");
```

It's

```
copy('\\PCNAME\c$\path\to\file',"filename");
```

Notice the c$ (hidden share), but why not create a publicly accessible share?

Edit: Also notice the single quotes, this is in order to preserve the backslashes (you were right @Esailija)

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes, the string is actually `\PCNAME\c$\path oile`. For example `"\t"` is the tab character, not literally `'\t'`"

Comment: Thanks to both of you Esailija and Gerald Versluis !!
It was a problem of **Quotes**.

Comment: however it worked well for me. I have another doubt in syntax

`$db = new PDO('sqlite:\\\\PCNAME\c$\path\to\file\main.db');`

is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

you have to map the drive first..

then pass proper drive location to copy the file.. for e.g. your mapped drive is g:\Program Files\file_name then pass that location to copy() function

Hope this will helps you.